# Inkscape Rotate Copies path effect deforms object

Tags: inkscape, path-effects

Using Inkscape 1.1 I have a triangle aligned with a circle and want to have 4 copies of the triangle at each side of the circle. When using the Rotate Copies Live Path Effect and snapping the origin to the circle midpoint, the triangles east and west get deformed and are far away from the circle.

How should I use the Rotate Copies effect to get a fully symmetrical picture?

[image: result of Rotate Copies on top triangle]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some investigation, it would appear that if you have any transforms applied to a shape, such as a stretched triangle, the Rotate Copies LPE effect will itself also be tranformed. This is perhaps something which could be considered a bug. It's unexpected behaviour at the very least.

So, with that in mind, here are a couple of possible fixes, all of which are simply designed to avoid transforms altogether:

1. Draw the triangle using the Stars and Polygon tool, do *Path > Object to path*, but then instead of stretching it, use the Edit Paths by Nodes tool to change the shape of the triangle, thus avoiding a transform.

or

2. Draw the triangle using the Bézier tool instead to avoid creating any transforms. In other words, don't squish or stretch the shape.

or

3. Use *Extensions > Modify Path > Apply Transform* on a shape you already transformed, to remove the transform before applying the effect.

Now it should work as expected.

Example

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This works. I did not know that Transformations are a thing in Inkscape that I should pay attention to. I already experimented with converting to path but only after I scaled the triangle. Doing it the other way around was the solution.

Comment: @Emile - yeah that would work too. In fact any way of avoiding or removing transforms will work.  Even deleting the transform from the XML editor is possible

Comment: Agree, I'd recommend reporting the problem at https://inkscape.org/report .

Answer (score 1):

Not asked but do not tease yourself with the complexity of that effect.

Make a triangle and 3 copies. Make the copies with Ctrl+D. rotate them with the fast 90 degrees rotate buttons. It takes about 15 seconds. Draw the 1st triangle by holding Ctrl for known straight position.

Place them on a circle which is converted to path to have 4 symmetrical nodes. Have point snaps on for exact snapping.

Scale the circle to the wanted size. Hold Shift+Ctrl to keep the center or input the size as numbers.

[image]

Comment: This is more or less the work-around that I used (though your method is a bit smarter). I asked the question to learn about Inkscape because it bothers me that I seem to miss something obvious.

Comment: I have never got with that effect the result that I wanted beforehand. Sometimes the unexpected result has been useful.